# JNI Call to Authenticate user using LogonUser?

Tags: c++, windows, authentication, java-native-interface

C++ noob here wonding how i can authenticate a Windows User via Java servlet.

Here is the code i have put together to take in a JNI call from my java servlet with the user's username domain and password:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <stdlib.h> 

#include "Validate.h"    

JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL Java_Validate_takeInfo(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj, jstring domain, jstring id, jstring idca, jstring password) 
{
    const char *nt_domain;
    const char *nt_id;
    const char *nt_idca;
    const char *nt_password;

    nt_domain = env->GetStringUTFChars(domain, NULL);
    nt_id = env->GetStringUTFChars(id, NULL);
    nt_idca= env->GetStringUTFChars(idca, NULL);
    nt_password = env->GetStringUTFChars(password, NULL);

    handle hToken = 0;
    char *otherString;
    otherString = LogonUser(nt_id, nt_domain, nt_password, LOGON32_LOGON_NETWORK, LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT, &hToken );

    jstring newString = env->NewStringUTF((const char*)otherString);
    return newString;
}
```

I get these errors when trying to compile:

```
D:\JNI\Validate.cpp(21) : error C2065: 'handle' : undeclared identifier
D:\JNI\Validate.cpp(21) : error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before
ier 'hToken'
D:\JNI\Validate.cpp(21) : error C2065: 'hToken' : undeclared identifier
D:\JNI\Validate.cpp(24) : error C2065: 'LOGON32_LOGON_NETWORK' : undeclar
tifier
D:\JNI\Validate.cpp(24) : error C2065: 'LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT' : undec
dentifier
D:\JNI\Validate.cpp(24) : error C3861: 'LogonUser': identifier not found
```

I am assuming i am not including something i need. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That your compiler couldn't find LogonUser suggests that you're missing the windows headers.  Include windows.h

Also, the generic windows handle type is spelled HANDLE, all in caps.

See [the `LogonUser` docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa378184(VS.85).aspx) for more details.